# .mov file not video playing

Tags: 10.10, codecs, totem

I have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras but when I play a movie such as this http://media.railscasts.com/videos/250_authentication_from_scratch.mov it plays the sound but the video is just a black screen.

It does the same in several different media players VLC, Totem, Bansheee. The BBC Iplayer and Youtube work fine.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing some third party software sources! Yay

Comment: Any specific sources causing problems?

Comment: Unity 2-D I think